# Execute angular code before Karma run all tests?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to execute some sort of initialization coding in karma? I need to run a code like this before my tests get executed:

```
angular.module('module.common.brand', []).constant('BRAND', 'brandname');
```

My app currently requires this module (and this constant) but today this is currently initialized in a funky way that my karma doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As any other JS file, initialization file should be specified in Karma configuration (`files` option), right before `test/*.spec.js`.

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize it was this simple! Cheers.

Comment: how does it know to execute first file for every test file, and not execute every test file for every test file?

Comment: @trusktr I'm not sure what you mean. `files` option just specifies which files should be loaded by Karma and the order in which they are loaded. It doesn't matter whether they are test files or not. They are just loaded.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize it was equivalent to concatenation (script tags). I was thinking it was a list of allowed files, but that they'd be treated as modules that import each other, they way newer runners (like Jest) work by default (relying on CommonJS for the runtime module format). So that's why I though, "how would sticking a file at the top of the list make it magically imported inside all my modules?". I get it now, thanks!