# Adding Custom Boilerplate Code in Jasmine Test File

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Basically, every unit test in my application is going to need this WINDOW provider specified.  Rather than having to add it manually each time a component is creates, is there a way of modifying the boilerplate code generation of the .spec.ts file or is there another way of making this provider available to every test in the application?

```
      beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      /* other stuff*/
      providers: [{ provide: WINDOW, useValue: mockWindow }],/* always need this entry*/
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

Update:  Tried PLB's suggestion by putting this block in a separate file and including it in karma.config as suggested

```
beforeEach(
waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{ provide: WINDOW, useValue: mockWindow }],
    }).compileComponents();
}),
```

)

But of course, that providers array just gets overwritten in ever subsequent .spec.ts with a providers array.

Comment: maybe something like this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820824/execute-angular-code-before-karma-run-all-tests

Comment: Thanks, see my update